# Remove X button in input - Metro

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs

I write a Metro program in Javascript. The problem is Windows8 automatically adds an X button to it. Now how to edit or remove that button? Below is my layout, the X button overlaps the email input.

[image]

Comment: Override the style of the textbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Details are here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465498.aspx

You need to use the -ms-clear pseudo element, and style it either as you need it, or display none it:

```
input::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that you likely want to not display none it, since this removes the easy-to-touch X that removes the current input.